# Type mismatch: inferred type is com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.User but com.example.socialmediaapp.model.User was expected

Tags: android, firebase

Error is showing for the user when passed in post i.e val post = Post(text, **user**, currentTime)

class PostDao {

```
private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private val postCollection = db.collection("posts")
private val auth = Firebase.auth


fun addPost(text:String){
    val currentUserId = auth.currentUser!!.uid
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val userDao = UserDao()

        //getting actual user document from the task through user id
        val user = userDao.getUserById(currentUserId).await().toObject(User::class.java)!!

        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val post = Post(text, user, currentTime)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Post data class :

```
data class Post(
    val text:String = "",
    val createdBy: User = User(),
    val createdAt:Long = 0L,
    val likedBy: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
)
```

Please help me solve this issue.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not using same user object at both of the places. You need to declare and get same type of USER class in your code.

You are trying to get the value of com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.User but com.example.socialmediaapp.model.User is expected as per your code.

Comment: Thank you for answering . But what you said that does not solve my problem . I know why the error is showing there but don't know how to fix that . I would really appreciate if you help me with that.

Comment: You are confusing with the User model class. Do change your apps class name to UserData then you will be able to differentiate between both of the classes. or share the code of Post method. and the User class that you have declared in your project.